# relative path for excel in spring configuration file

Tags: java, spring, excel, web

I have written a program to fetch fire sql queries to Excel and get the data. I have used jdbc-odbc connection for that purpose as follows.

```
Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
c = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:Driver={Microsoft Excel Driver (*.xls)};DBQ="                            
                            + request.getSession().getServletContext().getRealPath("WEB-INF")+"\\TCCAddress.xls");
stmnt = c.createStatement();
String query = "select * from [TCC_001$]";
ResultSet rs = stmnt.executeQuery(query);
```

but i am using spring and i want to create a connection using spring datasource. i tried below but its not working.

```
<bean id="excelDB"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver" />
        <property name="url">
            <value>jdbc:odbc:Driver={Microsoft Excel Driver (*.xls)};DBQ=classpath:/WEB-INF/TCCAddress.xls</value>
        </property>
</bean>
```

it gives error as

```
Failure creating file.
```

if i use

```
<property name="url">
                <value>jdbc:odbc:Driver={Microsoft Excel Driver (*.xls)};DBQ=D:/TCCAddress.xls</value>
</property>
```

it works fine i can connect to excel and fetch the data.

how can i give **relative path** for **TCCAddress.xls**

**Note** I don't want to use absolute path like"D:/TCCAddress.xls"

Answer (score 1):

Seeing your question I think you only need the relative path of xls file.Once you get that path you can do further things.

Let me try to explain how can you get relative path of any resource.

Suppose you had put your xls or any kind of resources  in "/WEB-INF/classes/".You can check this by seeing your war file.

Now you want path of that resource(here resource is xls file) after the deployment then you can do like

You can get path by this line of code.

```
String path = this.getClass().getResource("/WEB-INF/classes/xyz.xls").getPath();
```

Here your resource location in war file never going to change and also that would be known to you.So pass that in getResource() method.

Here You wants to change spring configuration runtime so for that in your problem you can use  **BeanPostProcessor interface**. It can be used to do custom instantiation logic for several beans wheras the others are defined on a per bean basis..

In that you can find two methods mentioned below

1. postProcessAfterInitialization
2. postProcessBeforeInitialization

Read this documentation of Spring community [Customizing beans using a BeanPostProcessor](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/spring-framework-reference.html#beans-factory-extension-bpp) and [Customizing configuration metadata with a BeanFactoryPostProcessor](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/spring-framework-reference.html#beans-factory-extension-factory-postprocessors).

You can achieve your goal through it.

Comment: i am able to get the path using request.getSession().getServletContext().getRealPath("WEB-INF") my question is i want to configure the path in spring configuratiuon file