# Spring Java mulipart data file save

Tags: java, spring, file-upload

I work with Spring.

I have this code on my controller

```
@Controller
public class FileUploadController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/file-upload", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    @ResponseBody
    public String uploadFile(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file, HttpServletRequest request,ServletContext context) throws IOException {

        if(!file.isEmpty()) {

            file.transferTo(new File("/data.xml"));     
            return "ok";
        } 
        else {
            return "Empty";
        }
    }
}
```

i just want to save the uploaded file to the root directory.

It seem to me that i use a absolute Path to the Root, but i don't now how i can find that out.

Can anybody help me ?

Comment: Root directory of Tomcat, the file system, something else?

Comment: yes of the tomcat, or better the project root

Comment: Is your application is sessionless?

Answer (score 1):

You can get real path with 
[HttpServletRequest.getSession().getServletContext()](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html#getServletContext%28%29) but this will be helpful If your application has session.If your application is sessionless than you can do by implementing [ServletContextAware](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/context/ServletContextAware.html).

If application has session then

```
request.getSession().getServletContext().getRealPath("WEB-INF");
```

also one another way to get real path.

Comment: You can do with resource loader.See my this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21728168/relative-path-for-excel-in-spring-configuration-file/21728563#21728563 or see my edited answer.

Comment: What is the error you get in ? Tried once by giving static path and make confirm your code except this is working fine or not ? and then try to do with relative path.

Answer (score 0):

Get the class loader from one of your objects and use that to get its local path.  That will give you a path from your execution point in Tomcat.  From there you can find the location you want.

obj.getClass().getResource("/");

Comment: can you please explain me that in more detail. i don't understand class loader...

Comment: The exact code is provided.  What other detail do you need?

Comment: what is obj ? Is that a locale variable ? And what type ?

Comment: As I said that is any of the objects you are using.  It could be your file object.

Comment: I tried  String path = file.getClass().getResource("/").toString(); without success

Comment: @zoom23 Try like this String path = this.getClass().getResource("/").toString();Here Obj is that class only.

Comment: Without success meaning what?  Post like it "did not work" are one the best ways to get no response.  This is a technical forum you have to provide specific information.  What did or did not happen?